# small VB.net school project with arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Hi everyone i am new here, im trying to do a small project in vb.net that uses a textbox and a button to populate an array(23). my variables are stored in a modules and when i input a text in the textbox and click on the button it is suppose to add the item to  the array. if the array is full then the button should be disabled so here is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If counter < 23 Then
        array1(counter) = TextBox1.Text
        counter = +1
    Else
        Button1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

here are the global variables

```
Module Module1
    Public array1(24) As String
    Public counter As Integer
End Module
```

the project run but when i click on the button several times the button doesn't disable i think it is because the counter is not increasing.

Comment: try `If counter <= 23 Then`

Comment: its giving the same result

Comment: ok nvm, i had to look closer.
Its because you have `counter = +1`
you have to use `counter += 1`
like that, its like counter is always 1

Comment: I added a solution to this problem, good luck with the school project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is how you are adding 1 to your counter

You have `counter = +1` you have to use `counter += 1`

Here's how you should do it:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If counter <= 23 Then
            array1(counter) = TextBox1.Text
            counter += 1
            If counter = 24 Then Button1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
```